# What is the Fat Arrow function's / Callback's type?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, callback

Pretty straight forward question. I come from a Qt/C++ background, and so I regard it as good practice to be explicit, thus

```js
protected sanityCheck() : void { ... } // Braced and Typepilled
protected sanityCheck() { ... }        // Extremely stupid and dangerous
```

Well, how do I be explicit with this:

```js
protected checkRadio( index : number ) : ????? // "Function" type does not work
{
        return (event: React.MouseEvent) => 
        {
                let radioIndex : HTMLInputElement 
                        = document.getElementsByName(this.question())[index] 
                        as HTMLInputElement;
                radioIndex.checked = true;
                event.preventDefault();
        }
}
```

Most types I have tried has resulted in

```js
Type 'void' is not assignable to type 
'((event: MouseEvent<HTMLLIElement, MouseEvent>) => void) | undefined'.  TS2322
```

When I checked the documentation, it doesn't say anything. When I checked the typeof, it just said `function`. I get the impression that I could define my own type, but I want a one time, one type solution that is as specific as possible.

The best I can do thus far though, is `any`, which is the least specific type.

So what are the most specific and explicit types I can use for this function?

Thanks.

Comment: Why doesn't `Function` work? [It does for me](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBAFgUwgawEoEMAm8AFIjGPmgB6IBciYIAtgEZoBOiAlLYgGLjR4SAPTDEAIn6RYCcYigBPAA5pE+OGgDO9OFEQB3OG0wAoAN4nEV61bZooINkiLcAvAD5EZgL4nvQA). It's not the most specific type but it *does* cover your case. Also, arrow functions are functions - you can specify the specific interface it would be (e.g., takes a React event, returns void) but they won't really be treated differently when it comes to type checking.

Comment: @VLAZ https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/XFmnPygFrK/ << This is a class member of `class QPoll<T extends string> extends React.Component<Props<T>, State>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `React.EventHandler<React.SyntheticEvent>` or `React.EventHandler<any>` as return type

Comment: Worked well; thanks Julia. Before I can accept, care to give a quick rundown of a `React.SyntheticEvent` ?

Comment: @Akiva https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html
Also check this, it might help you with types https://github.com/typescript-cheatsheets/react-typescript-cheatsheet